# How to transform dataframe to from-to pairs?

Tags: python, pandas, transformation, shift

If I have a dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
...     ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
...     ['E', 'B', 'C']
... ])
>>> df
   0  1  2     3
0  A  B  C     D
1  E  B  C  None
>>>
```

I shoudl transform the dataframe to two columns format:

```
x, y
-----
A, B
B, C
C, D
E, B
B, C
```

For each row, from left to right, take two neighbor values and make a pair of it.
It is kind of from-to if you consider each row as a path.

How to do the transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `explode` with `zip`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x : list(zip(x.dropna()[:-1],x.dropna()[1:])),axis=1).explode().tolist())
Out[336]: 
   0  1
0  A  B
1  B  C
2  C  D
3  E  B
4  B  C
```

Update

```
s=df.apply(lambda x : list(zip(x.dropna()[:-1],x.dropna()[1:])),axis=1).explode()
s=pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index)

s
Out[340]: 
   0  1
0  A  B
0  B  C
0  C  D
1  E  B
1  B  C
```

Comment: I missed explode. It works. Thank you very much YOBEN_S.

Comment: I forgot to say that I have to keep index in order to know from which row I have pair. So, for example, AB, BC, CD are coming from the first row, and EB BC from second.

Comment: @user3225309 check it again  :-) easy fix

Answer (score 0):

Pre-preparing the data could help too:

```py
import pandas as pd

inp = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       ['E', 'B', 'C']]

# Convert beforehand
inp2 = [[[i[k], i[k+1]] for k in range(len(i)-1)] for i in inp]
inp2 = inp2[0] + inp2[1]

df = pd.DataFrame(inp2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
   0  1
0  A  B
1  B  C
2  C  D
3  E  B
4  B  C
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that YOBEN_S's solution is more pythonic.